# How to write pointers of an object into a file?

Tags: c++, c

I have a situation where I need to store an object's pointer into an file and read it again in the same process.  How should I do it?

Right now I write/read like this:

```
    Myclass* class  = <valid pointer to Myclass>
    FILE* output_file = fopen(filename, "w");
    fwrite(class, sizeof(class), 1, output_file)

// and read it

    FILE* in_file = fopen(filename, "r");
    Myclass* class_read
    fread(class_read, sizeof(class_read), 1, in_file)
```

I don't see correct values when reading back.  I will read and write these files in the same address space.

Comment: Don't do it, reconsider what you want to write and read back.

Comment: While this is a BAD IDEA, the code should actually work.  In what way are the values "incorrect"?  Are they different? Can you print them out before and after?

Comment: class is a keyword in C++

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's your rationale for doing this?

Comment: If this program would ever be successful, that could be a serious security vulnerability.  Imagine some hacker noticing that file and changing it.

Comment: @Shaktal, @stefaanv: saving pointers to objects is (used to be?) popular in savegames. For example, the entire Command&Conquer line of games did it. When saving, they write the object's address and then bitwise copy the object into the stream. When loading, an object is constructed, it reads its data from the stream and tells a manager "I used to be at `0xf00c`, now I'm at `0xb44c`", later the manager rewrites ("swizzles") all the changed pointers. Here the pointer acts more like a "guid". (However, there was one pointer the developers missed and the community had to find/fix it).

Comment: @DCoder: in this case the pointer is used again, assuming it will always be in the same address space.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments, I had to do it to debug an issue, won't use it in production code :)

Comment: @stefaanv: Yes, I am aware of this. In the savegame scenario, if the game does not rewrite some pointer (because the developers forgot to add it to the "things to rewrite" list), it's left with the value loaded from file - if you load the save without restarting the application, you have a pretty similar situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read and write the pointer itself, you'll need to pass its address, not the address it points to:

```
fwrite(&class, sizeof(class), 1, output_file);
fread (&class_read, sizeof(class_read), 1, in_file);
       ^
```

You're instead writing the first few bytes of whatever `class` points to, then trying to read them back into whatever `class_read` points to (failing if it's not yet a valid pointer).

Comment: I missed that.  Well spotted.